# Probability of hitting time to be equal to particular $t$.

Tags: brownian-motion, stopping-times

Consider a geometric Brownian motion
$$
\frac{dA_t}{A_t}
=\mu \, dt + \sigma \, dz_t$$
with $z_t$: Wiener process, $t\in [0,T]$.

Define a hitting time

$$
\tau_{uc} = \inf\{t\in [0,T]: A_t \leq A_{uc}  \}
$$

for some $A_{uc}$.

I want to compute $\mathbb{P}\{\tau_{uc} = T \mid A_t\}$ when $A_s > A_{uc}$ for all $s\leq t$. I think the probability gotta be equal to zero, but do not know how to derive such a conclusion. Is there anyone who kindly answer this question?

Comment: I changed $\mu dt + \sigma dz_t$ to $\mu\,dt+\sigma\,dz_t.$ (I.e. with suitable horizontal spacing.) $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you very much!